# Get edges from tree represented as vector in Clojure

Tags: graph, clojure, tree, edges

I've got a tree like so:

```
[:root
  [:a [:b [:c [:g]]]]
  [:d [:e [:f [:g]]]]]
```

How can I get the edges, ie:

```
[[:root :a] [:root :d] [:a :b] [:b :c] [:c :g] [:d :e] [:e :f] [:f :g]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've come up with before I checked your answer.  Seems a bit more idiomatic unless I'm missing something.

```
(defn vec->edges [v-tree]
  (->> v-tree
       (tree-seq vector? next)
       (mapcat (fn [[a & children]]
                 (map (fn [[b]] [a b]) children)))))
```

Comment: You know, I have never used `tree-seq`. I forget it even existed!

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses a basic loop (no need for extra libraries or recursion):

```
(defn get-edges [tree]
  (loop [subtrees [tree]
         output []]
    (if (empty? subtrees)
      output
      (let [[[root & first-subtrees] & subtrees] subtrees]
        (recur (into subtrees first-subtrees)
               (into output (map #(-> [root (first %)])) first-subtrees))))))
```

Testing it on the example data:

```
(get-edges [:root
            [:a [:b [:c [:g]]]]
            [:d [:e [:f [:g]]]]])
;; => [[:root :a] [:root :d] [:d :e] [:e :f] [:f :g] [:a :b] [:b :c] [:c :g]]
```

Here is another approach based on lazy sequences:

```
(defn get-edges2 [tree]
  (->> [tree]
       (iterate #(into (rest %) (rest (first %))))
       (take-while seq)
       (mapcat (fn [subtrees]
                 (let [[[root & sub] & _] subtrees]
                   (map #(-> [root (first %)]) sub))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like the way you post your question Scott Klarenbach, it's really synthetic.

I proposed a solution in raw clojure. The tricky part was the location of the recursive call and how to handle the results of these recursive calls.

```clj
(def data
  [:root
   [:a [:b [:c [:g]]]]
   [:d [:e [:f [:g]]]]])

(defn get-edges [collection]
  (let [root (first collection)
        branches (rest collection)]
    (if (empty? branches)
      []
      (let [edges
            (mapv (fn [branch] [root (first branch)]) branches)
            sub-edges
            (->> branches
                 (mapcat (fn [branch] (get-edges branch)))
                 vec)]
        (if (empty? sub-edges)
          edges
          (vec (concat edges sub-edges)))))))

(get-edges data)
;; => [[:root :a] [:root :d] [:a :b] [:b :c] [:c :g] [:d :e] [:e :f] [:f :g]]
```

Comment: This code is great, but it can be simplified a lot without really changing the basic algorithm, notably removing all the `if`s. I simplified it to: `(defn get-edges [collection]
  (let [[root & branches] collection]
    (into (mapv (fn [branch] [root (first branch)]) branches)
          (mapcat get-edges)
          branches)))`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple built-in way to do this. The easiest way is to roll your own recursion.

Here is a solution with unique hiccup tags (no duplicates):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]))

(def result (atom []))

(s/defn walk-with-path-impl
  [path :- [s/Any] ; parent path is a vector
   user-fn
   data :- [s/Any]] ; each data item is a hiccup vector
  (let [tag       (xfirst data)
        path-next (append path tag)]
    (user-fn path data)
    (doseq [item (xrest data)]
      (walk-with-path-impl path-next user-fn item))))

(defn walk-with-path!
  [user-fn data]
  (walk-with-path-impl [] user-fn data))

(s/defn print-edge
  [path :- [s/Any] ; parent path is a vector
   data :- [s/Any]] ; each data item is a hiccup vector
  (when (not-empty? path)
    (let [parent-node (xlast path)
          tag         (xfirst data)
          edge        [parent-node tag]]
      (swap! result append edge))))
```

The unit test shows the input data & result

```
(dotest
  (let [tree [:root
              [:a
               [:b
                [:c
                 [:z]]]]
              [:d
               [:e
                [:f
                 [:g]]]]]]
    (reset! result [])
    (walk-with-path! print-edge tree)
    (is= @result
      [[:root :a] [:a :b] [:b :c] [:c :z]
       [:root :d] [:d :e] [:e :f] [:f :g]])))
```

[Here are the docs](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/) for convenience functions like `xfirst`, `append`, etc